# jpa avg(count(*))

Tags: jpa, count, average

Assum I have three tables User, Product and UserProduct. Once a user buys a product a record in the UserProduct table is created. 
I would like to calculate an average number of products being bought by users. I can do this with plain SQL on mySql RDBMS like as follows:

```
select avg(c) from (select count(*) as c from user_product up join user u on (up.user_id = u.id) group by u.id) as res
```

Any chance I can do the same with JPA?

Update: I know that subqueries may be used in the WHERE or HAVING clause only, but still...